# Javascript .map not returning correct components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just ran into a problem where my .map method is not returning the correct value. This project is built in react.

This is what I am looking for:

```
const prepInfo = [
        <PrepInfo uniqueKey={1} type={'prep'} quantity={'1'} unit={'unit'} suffix={'suffix'}/>,
        <PrepInfo uniqueKey={1} type={'prep'} quantity={'1'} unit={'unit'} suffix={'suffix'}/>,
    ];
```

And this is the code that was implemented to map the store values to the new array

```
const prepInfo = props.recipe.prep_info.map(function(record, index) {
        return (
            <PrepInfo uniqueKey={1} type={'prep'} quantity={'1'} unit={'unit'} suffix={'suffix'}/>
        )
    });
```

I am aware that it is not actually mapping the values, I was trying to pin point where the problem was and stubbed out the props for now. If anyone could help explain why the value returned by the .map method are not equal to the first array it would be very much appreciated.

edit: I know that they are not equal because downstream these components are being animated and the .map version causes the animation to break.

Comment: Not sure but may be because you want to store those in a variable rather than returning it from a react component. aka rendering it. I think if you want to store components in an array or variable, you should not write them in jsx syntax.

Comment: what does it is returning then?

Comment: Please describe exactly what your `map()` function is producing and how that differs from what you're attempting to produce.

Comment: From what I can see in the console, it looks identical. But once I pass it into a react-spring animation (that was working correctly with the first version) the animation breaks.

Comment: Also, if I try a `console.log(version1===version2)` it returns a false

Comment: You should use a different key for every component and not this `uniqueKey={1}`

Comment: Understood, I have changed both the keys to use the index as the key. Aside from that though, the first array (even with the `uniqueKey={1}`) continues to render properly

Comment: @TheFool could you possibly point me toward any resources with an alternate syntax to use?

Comment: when you write a components like this `<MyComponent someProp="foo" />` you are essentially just execution a function `myComponent({someProp: 'foo'})`. The return value of that function is some kind of dom element. It is what react will put on the page, the "actual HTML". That is why what you are doing doesnt make much sense. You invoke the function but expect the return value to be the function expression itself. And, I don't even know if you can invoke components, with JSX syntax, when they are not inside some react render function.

Comment: @TheFool I think we are on the same page with most of what you said. I am purposefully  adding the 'actual HTML' into an array so that it can be passed to an animation component similar to [this](https://codesandbox.io/embed/r5qmj8m6lq). The only other option I could think of is to build the prep info component into the animation component but then I would be tightly coupling two things that shouldn't be coupled (imo). I appreciate your response, if I figure out another way around it I will let you know!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a `key` to t the `PrepInfo` props.

```
const prepInfo = props.recipe.prep_info.map(function(record, index) {
    return (
        <PrepInfo key={record.someUniqueId} uniqueKey={1} type={'prep'} quantity={'1'} unit={'unit'} suffix={'suffix'}/>
    )
});
```

When you use map to create components, you need to give them a `key` so that react knows which is which.

[More in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this but it did not fix the problem.